# Two new binomial identities

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I have to compute the following values:

$$
1) \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k \binom{n-1}{k} \frac{k}{n-k}
$$

$$
2) \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^{n-k} \binom{n-1}{k} \frac{k}{n-k}
$$

How can I solve them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

As for $r\ge1, r!=r\cdot(r-1)!$

for $k\ge1,$

$$ \binom{n-1}{k} \frac{k}{n-k}=\dfrac{(n-1)!k}{k! (n-1-k)!\cdot (n-k)}=\dfrac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!\{n-1-(k-1)\}!}=\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$

We know, $\displaystyle(a+b)^m=\sum_{r=0}^m\binom mr a^{m-r}b^r$ for integer $m\ge1$

$\displaystyle a=1\implies(1+b)^m=\sum_{r=0}^m\binom mr b^r$

and

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^{n-k} \binom{n-1}{k} \frac{k}{n-k}=2^n\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k} \frac{k}{n-k}\left(\dfrac12\right)^k$$

Comment: So I obtain in the first case $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{k-1}2^k=2 \cdot 3^{n-1}-2^n$